# Model is duplicating output of 1 time instead of the 3 required

Tags: anylogic

In the model, there are 2 types of agents (FollowUp and NewConsult) that I would like to collect time for upon entering a seize block and upon seizing the resource in order to understand the time waiting in that block while running a parameters variation experiment. Each patient type has their respective variable of `timeEnterClerk` and the time is added to their respective `waitClerkTime` statistic. As seen in the output, each agent type is being given a single time, regardless of its the morning (time < 150), afternoon (time > 150), or entire day. I am confused as this is not the case when outputting the average for all agent types as seen in `waitClerkTime.add(time() - agent.timeEnterClerk );`, `waitClerkTimeMorn.add(time() - agent.timeEnterClerk );`, and `waitClerkTimeAft.add(time() - agent.timeEnterClerk );`.

```
// On Enter

agent.timeEnterClerk = time();  

if (agent instanceof FollowUp)
    ((FollowUp)agent).timeEnterClerkFollowUp = time();

if (agent instanceof NewConsult)
    ((NewConsult)agent).timeEnterClerkNewConsult = time();

// On Seize

waitClerkTime.add(time() - agent.timeEnterClerk );

if (agent instanceof FollowUp)
    waitClerkTimeFollowUp.add(time() - ((FollowUp)agent).timeEnterClerkFollowUp );
if (agent instanceof NewConsult)
    waitClerkTimeNewConsult.add(time() - ((NewConsult)agent).timeEnterClerkNewConsult );

if (time() < 150)
    
    waitClerkTimeMorn.add(time() - agent.timeEnterClerk );

    if (agent instanceof FollowUp)
        waitClerkTimeMornFollowUp.add(time() - ((FollowUp)agent).timeEnterClerkFollowUp );
    if (agent instanceof NewConsult)
        waitClerkTimeMornNewConsult.add(time() - ((NewConsult)agent).timeEnterClerkNewConsult); 

        
if (time() > 150)
    
    waitClerkTimeAft.add(time() - agent.timeEnterClerk );

    if (agent instanceof FollowUp)
        waitClerkTimeAftFollowUp.add(time() - ((FollowUp)agent).timeEnterClerkFollowUp );
    if (agent instanceof NewConsult)
        waitClerkTimeAftNewConsult.add(time() - ((NewConsult)agent).timeEnterClerkNewConsult);
```

Parameters variation in After Simulation Run:

```
KneeClinicDataExport.setCellValue(root.waitClerkTime.mean(), 1, row + 1, 1); 
KneeClinicDataExport.setCellValue(root.waitClerkTimeMorn.mean(), 1, row + 1, 2); 
KneeClinicDataExport.setCellValue(root.waitClerkTimeAft.mean(), 1, row + 1, 3);

KneeClinicDataExport.setCellValue(root.waitClerkTimeFollowUp.mean(), 1, row + 1, 4); 
KneeClinicDataExport.setCellValue(root.waitClerkTimeMornFollowUp.mean(), 1, row + 1, 5); 
KneeClinicDataExport.setCellValue(root.waitClerkTimeAftFollowUp.mean(), 1, row + 1, 6);

KneeClinicDataExport.setCellValue(root.waitClerkTimeNewConsult.mean(), 1, row + 1, 7); 
KneeClinicDataExport.setCellValue(root.waitClerkTimeMornNewConsult.mean(), 1, row + 1, 8); 
KneeClinicDataExport.setCellValue(root.waitClerkTimeAftNewConsult.mean(), 1, row + 1, 9);

KneeClinicDataExport.setCellValue(root.waitClerkTimeRevision.mean(), 1, row + 1, 10); 
KneeClinicDataExport.setCellValue(root.waitClerkTimeMornRevision.mean(), 1, row + 1, 11); 
KneeClinicDataExport.setCellValue(root.waitClerkTimeAftRevision.mean(), 1, row + 1, 12);

row++;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason you have this problem is that you are not using brackets for your if statements

In the following case, both statements are executed when the condition is true

```
if(conditions){
    statementA;
    statementB;
}
```

In the following example, only statementA is executed when the condition is true, but statementB is executed always

```
if(conditions)
statementA;
statementB;
```